# Evaluating the surface integral over subset of Cylinder surface

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, surface-integrals

I am preparing for the GRE math subject test.
And I am not sure whether my solution to this surface integral problem is correct.

## Problem

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTZuD.png)

> 2. Surface $S$ is part of $x^2 +y^2 = 1$ between planes $z = 0$ and $x+y+z = 2$, a vector field $\vec F = x\vec i +y\vec j+z\vec k$, what is the value of integration 
>      $$\iint\limits_S\vec F\cdot \vec n\,\textrm dS,$$
>      where $\vec n$ is the unit normal vector of $S$?

## My answer

Note that $\vec{n} = (x, y)$,
\begin{equation}
    \iint_S \vec{F}  \vec{n} dS
    =
    \iint_S (x^2+y^2) dS
    =
    \iint_S dS
\end{equation}
To evaluate the area of $S$, let $x= \cos\theta$ and $y= \sin\theta$, then 
\begin{equation}
    \vec{r} = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, z)
\end{equation}
hence
\begin{equation}
    \iint_S dS = \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^{2-\cos\theta-\sin\theta} dz
    = 4\pi
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance for pointing my mistakes if any.

Comment: @Triatticus thanks for advice. But it seems that according to the problem, I am not asked to evaluate the flux through the top and bottom surface. Because in either case, the coordinates will not satisfies the equation of the unit circle unless it is on the boundary of the circle.

Comment: Yeah I reread it and so far it does look like only the lateral surface, if that's the case everything looks fine. If you had to integrate over the top and bottom those are obviously different constraints than the sides and require different bounds on the integrals